# Pessimistic Ruby operator for Ruby version in Gemfile causes error

Tags: ruby

In our Gemfile we have the following: `ruby '~> 2.5.0'`

So that we enforce that at least `2.5.0` is installed but below `2.6.0`

And we have installed Ruby `2.5.3p105` on our server to run this application... so we are within the version required by our Gemfile.

However when we start Puma we are seeing the error: `Your Ruby version is 2.5.3, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.5.0`

How is this possible? The pessimistic operator should of done:

`>= 2.5.0 && < 2.6.0`

If we comment that line out of our Gemfile then it works...?

We're using Bundler 1.17.3.

Comment: What happens if you replace it with `ruby '>= 2.5.0', '< 2.6'`? Which would be identical like you said.

Comment: @JohanWentholt It doesn't like that. I don't believe that's valid code: `[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer. Bundler cannot continue.`

Comment: I have no problems with the above code. You just call the method `ruby` with 2 arguments instead of one. My output is: `Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.5.0, < 2.6` (which is correct since my Ruby version doesn't match)

Comment: @JohanWentholt Not sure then.. but this is what is happening with that code: `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb:4:in '[]':  (Bundler::Dsl::DSLError)
[!] There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /srv/portal/releases/2019-02-21-15-55-45/Gemfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  ruby('>= 2.5.0', '< 2.6')
 #  source 'https://rubygems.org'
 #  -------------------------------------------`

Comment: This is using `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` and `bundler 1.17.3`.

Comment: Is this issue also present in a newly initialized bundler directory? (`mkdir foo; cd foo; bundler init; echo "ruby '~> 2.5.0'" >> Gemfile; bundle install`)

Comment: So we updated the packages on the ubuntu box and it fixed the issue... weird!!!

Comment: Strange. At least the problem is solved. Consider posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

We're not entirely sure what the issue was or what the actual fix was for this...

But basically after trying the following: `ruby '>= 2.5.0', '< 2.6'` as suggested in the comments of the original question we encountered this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb:4:in '[]': (Bundler::Dsl::DSLError)
[!] There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer. Bundler cannot continue.
# from /srv/portal/releases/2019-02-21-15-55-45/Gemfile:1 
# ------------------------------------------- 
> ruby('>= 2.5.0', '< 2.6') 
# source 'https://rubygems.org' 
# -------------------------------------------
```

Which made us think there was something wrong with the actual Ruby installed... as when trying this locally it was fine and we also tried it on a different server and it was also working with no issues.

So we uninstalled Ruby, removed all the Gems and then did a full package update on the Ubuntu dist we had running and then re-installed bundler and all the gems again and it worked... so it seems that it was something around one of the packages that was causing Ruby to behave weirdly and not understand how to use the ruby method in the Gemfile correctly causing the aforementioned issues.

Hopefully if anyone else encounters similar problems this will help...

Answer (score 0):

From the bundler guides on specifying gems:

> gem "rails", "~> 4.0.0" # which is same as gem "rails", ">= 4.0.0", "< 4.1.0"

Perhaps the explicit form will provide better results?

The guide in question specifies that it was written for bundler 1.12